# Generar tablas dinamicas para word mediante codigo en VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word

Hola chico tengo una consulta pasa que estoy generando una tabla para un documento word mediante codigo, tengo un word que uso como base donde viene el titulo un parrafo y una fila con 5 columna que son los encabezado que quiero para la tabla que genero por vb.net, luego quiero que inserte la tabla, la tabla la inserto mediante codigo y no con etiquetas porque es una tabla variable ya que puede tener N filas mi codigo es el siguiente

```
   Dim rng As Word.Range = oDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=474, End:=474) // en esta linea declaro la tabla y con range le indico donde posicionarse
                        With rng
                            With .Font
                                .Name = "calibri light"
                            End With
                            .Font.Size = 10
                            .SetRange(rng.End, rng.End)
                        End With
                        'contadoint += 2
                        rng.Tables.Add(Range:=rng, NumRows:=contadoint, NumColumns:=5)
                        With rng.Tables.Item(1)
                            .Range.Font.Size = 11
                            .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Columns.DistributeWidth()
                        End With
```

mi  problema es que al usar range tambien el lugar de donde se genera la tabla derrepente se genera en la posicion que quiero pero dependiendo de las filas y de otros datos se desarma el orden, lo que me gustaria es fijarle una posicion y que se cree desde ahi

de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Te falta ser más específico para ayudarte, falta información

Comment: Lo que necesito es que la tabla que se esta creando por programación quede en una posición fija y no se mueva cuando se genere el documento